# Using react-modal-hook causes TypeError: Object(...)() is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to use an additional library that makes using react-modals easier. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-hook). When I'm using raw react-modals (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) everything is working fine but when I'm trying to use react-modal-hook I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: Object(...)() is null
SignInForm
src/components/login/SignInForm.tsx:18
```

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { ModalProvider } from "react-modal-hook";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ModalProvider>
      <App />
    </ModalProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Home.tsx (from here I'm trying to open the modal):

```
import React from "react";
import { useOktaAuth } from "@okta/okta-react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useModal } from "react-modal-hook";
import ReactModal from "react-modal";
import SignInForm from "../components/login/SignInForm";

const Home = () => {
    const { authState } = useOktaAuth();
    const { push } = useHistory()
    const [showModal, hideModal] = useModal(() => (
        <ReactModal isOpen>
          <SignInForm />
        </ReactModal>
      ));
    
    if (authState.isPending) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>auth token: </span>
            {authState.accessToken?.accessToken}
            <br />
            {authState.isAuthenticated ?
                <button onClick={() => push('/home')}>Logout</button> :
                <button onClick={showModal}>Login</button>}
        </div>
    )
}
    ;

export default Home;
```

and SignInForm.tsx (this one I want to display as modal):

```
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import * as yup from "yup";

const SignInForm = () => {

    const schema = yup.object({
        username: yup.string().required("Username is required"),
        password: yup.string().required("Password is required")
    });

    type FormValues = yup.InferType<typeof schema>;

    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isValid } } = useForm<FormValues>({ resolver: yupResolver(schema), mode: 'all' });
    const { oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();

    const onSubmit = async (data: FormValues) => {
        try {
            const response = await oktaAuth.signInWithCredentials({ username: data.username, password: data.password })
            oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect({ sessionToken: response.sessionToken })
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error("Login failed")
        }

    }

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
...
```

By looking on that error I'm thinking that I have problem somewhere around `<ModalProvider>`, am I right? The line to which the error is referring to is:

```
const { oktaAuth } = useOktaAuth();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found the reason for that error. Hook `useOktaAuth()` can be only used inside `<Security>` and in my case it was

```
    <ModalProvider>
      <App />
    </ModalProvider>
```

and inside that `<App />` I had already `Router` component.
I changed it to:

```
        <Router>
            <Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} onAuthRequired={onAuthRequired} restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}>
                <ModalProvider>
                <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home} />
                <Route path='/login' render={() => <SignIn />} />
                <Route path='/login/callback' component={LoginCallback} />
                </ModalProvider>
            </Security>
        </Router>
```

and now it's working fine